# Touch Location gets messy after ZOOM In and ZOOM out in Cocos 2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

i am having trouble selecting my sprites when i zoom out or zoom in. I feel that a scaling issue is causing this after zoom in / zoom out. I am not good at maths but i think there might be mathematical formula to calculate the touch location after zoom out and zoom in . O mean to say that when scale is 1 => x,y = 51,85 and when scale is 2 => x,y = -137,15 and in the end when scale is 0.5 => x,y = 146,123

Kindly help out!

Answer (score 0):

this code scale my Layer by 2 to specific location

```
    [layer setScale:2];
    layer.position=ccp(240/2+40,160*1.5);
    double dx=(touchLocation.x*2-240);
    double dy=(touchLocation.y*2-160);
    layer.position=ccp(inGamePlay.position.x-dx,inGamePlay.position.y-dy);
```